# Project Euler #19 - Counting Sundays Problem

Tags: python

I have been working on this problem for a while. It's a problem that says you have to find how many Sundays land on the First of the Month in the years 1901 to 2000. I've made it mostly work, but it still outputs 173, instead of 171 (the correct answer).

Does anyone why this is?

```
months = {1:31, 2:28, 3:31, 4:30, 5:31, 6:30, 7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31}

start, end = 1900, 2001

years = range(start, end)
leap_years = range(1904, 2001, 4)

Sundays = 0
days = 1
for year in years:
  if year in leap_years:
    months[2] = 29 
  else:
    months[2] = 28

  for month in range(1, 13):
    for day in range(1, months[month]+1):
      if days == 7:
        if day == 1:
          print(year, month, day)
          Sundays += 1
        days = 1
      else:
        days += 1


print(Sundays)
```

Comment: For Project Euler problems, you're expected to be a little clever.  Brute force iterating through every day in a 100 year span works, but it isn't how the problem is meant to be solved.

Comment: You could use [weekday](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.weekday) from the [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module.

Comment: @MarkRansom Taking a tenth of the human time to write a program that take ten times the computer time is, arguably, a legitimate strategic choice, especially when the "slow" program take a fraction of a second. Using a dictionary for sequential data is a bit weird, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is completely correct - just the inputs are wrong. `start` and `end` should be:

```py
start, end = 1901, 2000
```

The `range(a, b)` function is not inclusive of `b`, but it is inclusive of `a`. Thus `start` should be 1901 instead of 1900.

The `end` is a bit more tricky, you have to think about the phrasing of the question:

> ... in the years 1901 to 2000

Think about it - this means every day up to, but not including, Jan 1 2000. Thus the last year that you actually want to iterate through and check is 1999. Thus, setting `end` to 2000 will cause the `range()` function to return all the years up to, but not including, 2000. Which is exactly what the question asks for.

Comment: Everything you say is correct, but changing `start` from 1900 to 1901 introduces another bug.

Comment: "The end is a bit more tricky, you have to think about the phrasing of the question:

... in the years 1901 to 2000

Think about it - this means every day up to, but not including, Jan 1 2000. " Did you read the question? https://projecteuler.net/problem=19

Answer (score 0):

Your `days` *assumes* `day` equal 1 is `days` equal 1, (Monday) starting from the first month (and then progresses through the months, years). I don't think this will accurately calculate the count of Sundays that fall on the first of each month over the years.

If you enter the following code at the beginning of your program (and delete the line before your loop that says `days = 1`), it will correctly give the number of Sundays == 171. This will start out the day of week for the first day of the first month of the first year accurately.

```
from calendar import weekday
start, end = 1901, 2001
days = 1 + weekday(start, 1, 1)
```

Note that the `weekday` function uses zero based counting, (Monday through Sunday is 0 to 6) so that's why `1` is added to the result in the initialization of `days`. (Because your Monday to Sunday is 1 to 7).

Just to illustrate how the solution could find Sundays without iterating through every day of all the years:

```
from calendar import weekday

sundays = 0

for yr in range(1901, 2001):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        if weekday(yr, month, 1) == 6:
            sundays += 1

print(sundays) # prints 171
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

def sunday_finder(start_year , stop_year):
    recent_year = start_year
    counter = 0
    for course_of_y in range ((stop_year-start_year)+1): #to find The gap between years
        for month in range(1,13):                          #to ireration all months
            date = datetime.datetime(recent_year , month, 1)   #first day of every mounth
            if int(date.strftime("%w")) == 0:                
                counter += 1
        recent_year += 1         #to start next year in next itenration
    return counter
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.